implementing CPU cycle execution in my chip8 emulator using a 2D array of function pointers
I'm writing an chip8 emulator and I'm unsure if my cycle implementation is a good idea or not. As of now I have a 2D array (7x2) of function pointers that I use as an action queue, this is for actions that can be done in a single cycle (like writing to an address, fetching an opcode).
It's 2D because multiple actions can be taken in a single cycle, like fetching data and transforming it, and it's 7 pointers long because the longest instruction takes 7 cycles.
Is this a good way to do it or is there something more efficient? I'm just working on the 6502 emulation as of now since it's the heart of the machine, I'll have a thread scanning for input and do the PPU and APU later.

Do you really need to go so low-level? Is not enough emulating the opcodes? I don't get the relation between the chip-8 and the 6502.

The 6502 sure has great longevity.
